# Find a certain element in a collection and change it in Ruby

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3.2

The need I have is to set the `quantity` of a certain `item` in `@cart.line_items` collection where `@cart.line_item.id == line_item_id`. I wrote a code that should work, but my gut tells me it would be more simply.

```
def line_item_quantity(line_item_id, quantity)
    @cart.line_items.each {|item| item.quantity = quantity if (item.id == line_item_id)}
    respond_to do |format|
      format.js
    end
end
```

So what is the Ruby approach to make this code better?

Comment: You should set item.quantity = quantity instead of only item = quantity. But beside that, what's wrong with your approach?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the following code should work, but will raise an exception if no line_item is found

```
@cart.line_items.find(line_item_id).quantity = quantity
```

Comment: Most likely it won't be work because find returns Enumerator.

Comment: also `find` will just return first match not all